# Finding a birational transformation between elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, curves, elliptic-curves

> Birationally transform over $\mathbb{Q}$ the curve $Y^2=\frac{1}{3}X^3+4X^2+1$ to a curve of the form $Y^2=X^3+AX+B$, where $A$ and $B$ are integers.

I know that over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can birationally transform a curve of the form $y^2=$ cubic in $x$ to a curve of the form $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, for integers $A,B$, using only transformations of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (ax+b,cy)$. So the goal is to find a suitable map. For example, by looking at the coefficient of $X^3$, I think we could take $(x,y)\mapsto (3x,y)$ or something similar? But I can't figure out what the right mapping is. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the $5$ comes from ?

Comment: Multiply the equation by $81$.

Comment: @zwim typo- fixed now!

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit if we do that we get $(9y)^2=27x^3+324X^2+81$; how does this help though? I'm definitely missing something

Comment: @alidixon222 from the equation you have in this comment you can find a nice substitution

Comment: @OrazioCherubini we want $y\mapsto 9y$, but what about $x$? If for instance we had $(x,y)\mapsto (3x,9y)$, we wouldn't be able to get rid of the $X^2$ term?

Comment: @alidixon222, $y^2=\frac{x^3}{3}+4x^2+1 \implies Y^2 = X^3+36X^2+81$ with $(X,Y)=(3x,9y).$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/83916/f/1), minimal Weierstrass equation is $Y^2=X^3-432X+3537.$

Answer (score 0):

With $(a,b,c,d)$ integer, let's plug $\begin{cases}X=\frac ad x+\frac bd\\Y=\frac cd y\end{cases}\quad $ in $\ Y^2-(\frac 13X^3+4X^2+1)=0$

After reduction to the same denominator we get

$$-a^3x^3+(-12a^2d-3a^2b)x^2+(-24adb-3ab^2)x+3dc^2y^2-(12db^2+b^3+3d^3) = 0$$

First we eliminate the term in $x^2$ by setting $b=-4d$

We get $\ 3dc^2y^2-a^3x^3+48d^2ax-131d^3 = 0\ $ which is normalized to

$$y^2 = \frac{a^3}{3dc^2}\,x^3 - \frac{16ad}{c^2}\,x + \frac{131d^2}{3c^2}$$

And we try to make integer coefficients.

Let see if we can find something for simple choice $c=1$

$a$ must be multiple of $3$ (forced by $x^3$ coefficient).

But then $\frac{a^3}{3d}=\frac{27\alpha^3}{3d}=\frac{9\alpha^3}{d}$ so $d$ multiple of $9$ works and that clears also the constant coefficient.

So we can just take $a=3,b=-4,c=1,d=9$

> $(X,Y)\mapsto(\frac x3-\frac 49,\frac y9)\ $ gives $\ y^2=x^3-432x-3537$

Comment: Thanks! We want $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ though; is there a way to go from your result to this?

Comment: I modified my post to search directly for rational coefficient so this is better than my previous attempt. I hadn't read the wording correctly :-)